# Force a class to implement a method without restricting the parameters in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an interface that contain the method `void DoCommand();`. now I'll force all the child classes to inherit the base class method `DoCommand()`. but I need each class to define a different parameter for this method to serve the page with the proper parameters.

How can I do that ?
Is it even possible !

N.B: I'm building an ASP.NET web application and the page that will implement the method already inherits from the page base class, so I think Interface is my only option. as only one base class is allowed in inheritance of classes.

---

**Edit**

I hope illustrating what I need this for could let you help me to come up with a better design and stick to the rich concepts like OOP.

I have 19 pages, each page will need a method to collect data from the input controls in this page and put it in an object (19 pages .. 19 types of objects)

so I need Collect(); to be forced, then each page will take as a parameter the proper type of object .. does it make more sense ?

btw if you think that my design is totally wrong, a whole new design patterns are welcome (Y)

Comment: What do you mean a different parameter? Potentially you could do something like void DoCommand(object obj) in your interface, then restrict it in classes that inherit it. I believe as long as your parameter type is a type of object you should be good to go

Comment: Why do you need to do that? How do you intend to call it if you don't know which parameters it has?

Comment: @Prescott .. For example the method in the base class will be DoCommand. But child class [1] will implement it DoCommand(MyItem item) and child class [2] will implement it as DoCommand(Price price) .. hmm I'll try the Object thing!

Comment: @Lasse .. I can't call the method anyway unless I implement it, so I'll implement it in a given child class and define the proper parameters.

Comment: As long as one function in the class or any class that you inherit from impelents DoCommand(), all the classes can inherit from the interface.

Comment: Im not sure what you mean by "(19 pages .. 19 types of objects)" Can you show a code example of two different pages that needs to implement this collect function?

Comment: 19 Objects (Example: Cars, Tiers, AlertSystem, ...) .. 19 Pages to allow me to add (Cars, Tiers,...) to my system .. each object has a number of properties and the page contain the proper input controls to fill this object .. now each page that will implement Collect() will take a parameter of the target type .. say AddCars.aspx will have Collect(Cars newCar){ //Code to retrieve data from the controls and add them to the object: newCar}

Comment: Ok.. I've editied my answer, it might be something like that you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interface will need to have all the functions (with different parameter). There is no reason to have an interface otherwise

**Edit:** You might want something like this (using generics)

```
public interface ICollect<T>
{
    void Collect(T obj);
}

public class Car : ICollect<Car>
{
    public void Collect(Car obj)
    {
    //Do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: . the interface is just my tool to force the child classes to implement this method .. but each class will implement it with different code (which is the normal case) but also different parameter! .. it's not possible to do that by any means and still keep a good design pattern !?

Comment: So you only want to foce the name of the method? Thats not possible, and I cant see any use for that kind of implementation.

Comment: so you think I should just define the method in every page and kill the interface thing ?

Answer (score 4):

It's not possible.  The closest you can come is to have your method be generic and take a single generic argument:

```
protected abstract void DoCommand<T>(T parameter);
```

Short of that you'll have to use a property bag of some sort (like `NameValueCollection`).

Answer (score 2):

The best I can think of is:

```
interface IBlaBla
{
     void DoCommand(params object[] parameters);
}
```

and then each class receives the parameters as a sequence of objects.

Otherwise, you'll just have to define a brand new method for each class.

Answer (score 0):

It does not make sense. This violates the whole idea of polymorphism: the base class(or interface) has a method and child classes provide their own implementation. If you didn't mean to use a generic parameter, then the methods of your child classes are different from the base class, they just appear to have the same name. So you can't force your child classes to implement 'some routine with a given name but arbitrary parameters'.

Answer (score 0):

No, that's impossible. However, you can try this:

```
void DoCommand(params object[] args);
```